# Refresh Complete Event in Paging Toolbar in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: extjs

I am adding a paging toolbar from below code:

```
this.bbar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
    pageSize: this.pageSize,
    store: this.store,
    displayInfo: true,
    displayMsg: helpiq.i18.topiclist.display_msg,
    emptyMsg: helpiq.i18.topiclist.empty_msg     
});
```

Now I want to add an event that calls when the toolbar refresh action is completed and also one more event that calls when changing the page completes.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

Just add the change listener to the paging toolbar, it will be called after the completion of refresh event complete and also on page change event complete.

```
change: function() {
    // do here
}
```

This solution will solve both the problems of the question.